# How to integrate SMTP auth into a sendmail PHP script

Tags: php, email, server, smtp

Bear in mind, I am new to PHP

Hi, i'm having trouble sending SMTP mail from a script that only uses sendmail.

The below code is my original old code that works but that gives a warning on Gmail when viewed. It says this message can not be verified. I'm trying to send the user their credentials from a password reset form (I will be implementing this on the registration form as well).

Original Code:

```
    ##### Mail functions #####

    function sendLostPasswordEmail($myusername, $email, $newpassword)
    {

    global $domain;
    $message = "
    You have requested a new password on example.com

    Here is Your new password information:

    username:  $myusername
    password:  $newpassword


    Regards,
    example Administration
    ";

    if (sendMail($email, "Your password has been reset.", $message, "noreply@example.com"))
    {
    return true;
    } else
    {
    return false;
    }


    }

    function sendMail($to, $subject, $message, $from)
    {


    $from_header = "From: $from";

    if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $from_header))
    {
    return true;
    } else
    {
    return false;
    }
    return false;
    }

    function sendActivationEmail($myusername, $password, $uid, $email, $actcode)
    {
    global $domain;
    $link = "https://example.com/includes/activate.php?uid=$uid&actcode=$actcode";
    $message = "
    Thank you for registering on https://example.com,

    Your account information:

    username:  $myusername
    password:  $password

    Please click the link below to activate your account.

    $link

    Regards
    $domain Administration
    ";

    if (sendMail($email, "Please activate your account.", $message, "noreply@example.com"))
    {
    return true;
    } else
    {
    return false;
    }
    }

    ?>
```

Code to implement (I think)

```
    require_once "php/Mail/mail.php";

    $from = "Example Company <noreply@example.com>";
    $to = "<>";
    $subject = "Your Password Has Been Reset";
    $body = "$message";

    $host = "mail.example.com";
    $port = "465";
    $username = "noreply@example.com";
    $password = "***";

    $headers = array ('From' => $from,
    'To' => $to,
    'Subject' => $subject);
    $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
    array ('host' => $host,
    'port' => $port,
    'auth' => true,
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password));

    $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);
```

I believe the 2nd code snippet will fit in with the original somewhere, however, I have been trying for several hours to solve this problem to no avail. I appreciate any help, if you need to see the actual password recovery form code or think I could improve my question please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many reasons preventing you to send smtp email (supposing that you are use correct SMTP library)

- You are using port 465, this is likely connection using smtps, please check you host in phpinfo() if it supports open_ssl extension.
- Your host doesn't allow SMTP connection (A2hosting shared host for example)
- Your SMTP provider need verification from your domain to allow email to be sent.

Hope that can help.

Comment: My trouble is not the connection, but the implementation. I know how to connect to the SMTP server but not how to integrate the SMTP auth into my existing script. Thanks

Comment: Which library you are using? There are many libraries on Google, phpMailer, SwiftMailer ....

Comment: It is a Pear package http://pear.php.net/package/Mail/docs/1.4.1/Mail/Mail_smtp.html

Comment: Can you enable debug mode by passing `debug` => true and check the result?

Comment: I must have a large error in my code, the page just gives a 500 error.

Comment: I was simply using the wrong library. Thanks to all who helped!

Answer (score 0):

Try using [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). This tool is so powerful. You just need to include this to your website, configure and you are ready to go. Plus, good documentation and easy to understand.